# pyspark join two dataframes to find the mapped words in one dataframe for another dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to join a pyspark dataframe with another dataframe.

df1:

```
 id1 (string)    val1 (string)
 abc             "t-shirt shoes hat"
 hrf             "gloves bags"
```

df2: (load from csv)

```
 id2(string).    val2 (this column is a string on csv but it should be used as an array)
 t-shirt         [small t-short, large t-shirt]
 shoes           [red shoes, blue shoes]
 gloves          [mid gloves, large gloves]
 bags            [round bags, square bags]
```

After join:

```
 id1.            val1.               val1_mapped (array of string)
 abc             "t-shirt shoes hat" ["small t-short", "large t-shirt", "red shoes", "blue shoes"]  
 hrf             "gloves bags"       ["mid gloves", "large gloves", "round bags", "square bags"]
```

Each word in df1's "val1" should be mapped to the "val2" in df2 if the mapping exists.

The dataframe size could be large (500k rows).
How to use pyspark API to join them efficiently on pyspark ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid using `explode()` since the joining key in df1 is a string. Therefore, you need to split your string first:

```
df1 = df1.select('id1', 'val1' ,func.explode(func.split(func.col('val1'), ' ')).alias('id2'))
```

As you mentioned that the dataframe size could be large, not sure which dataframe are you referring, but in general the reference table (df2) should be much smaller than main dataframe (df1). Therefore you can use the `broacast()`:

```
df3 = df1.join(func.broadcast(df2), on='id2', how='left')
```

if both df1 and df2 are large, I prefer to collect the distinct value of joining key in df1 first and use it to filter the reference dataframe (df2), and then do the joining that same as above.

The remaining is just the list flattening:

```
df3.groupby('id1', 'val1').agg(func.flatten(func.collect_list('val2')).alias('val1_mapped'))
```

---

Edit: 2022-09-08
Since `flatten` is only available on spark version >= 2.4.0, you can create the df3 by:

```
df3\
    .groupBy('id1', 'val1')\
    .agg(func.collect_list('val2').alias('val1_mapped'))\
    .withColumn('val1_mapped', func.udf(lambda lsts: [element for lst in lsts for element in lst])('val1_mapped'))\
    .show(100, False)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I got an error "AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'flatten'".

Comment: @user3448011 which spark version are you using?

Comment: oyspark version is 2.3.2

Comment: thanks, I will try it. Why we have to use "agg" for "collect_list" ?

Comment: @user3448011 When you use `groupBy` in spark, a new object `GroupedData` will be generated and it doesn't have `collect_list` attribute. Therefore, you have to use `agg` to do the list collection.